# Need to embed a Gravity Forms form in a jQuery Tools tooltip in WordPress

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress, tooltip, gravity

I'm trying to embed a Gravity Forms form - http://gravityforms.com/ - within a jQuery Tools tooltip - http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html - on a WordPress website - http://buccan.mynewsitepreview.com/.

The jQuery Tools 'Tooltips' plugin works great; you can see it in action by hovering over any of the links in the footer. However, when using the shortcode to embed a Gravity Form, the `<span>` tag - which serves as a container for my tooltip - automatically closes. This puts the form outside of the tooltip content area.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can get the form to display inside the tooltip? I'd like to avoid using an overlay if possible, because I want the link to take the user to a contact page on click (in case javascript is disabled).

Thanks in advance!

*** EDIT ***

My question above may have been too vague...

By default, the jQuery Tools manual tooltip uses the element immediately next to the trigger as the tooltip content. My trigger is a link with the class 'tooltip_trigger', and the element that immediately follows is a span.

Within that span I would like to place a Gravity Form, but the PHP causes the span tag to close automatically before creating the HTML for the form.

So my real question is: Is there any way to change the behavior of the jQuery Tools tooltip so that it does not look for the element immediately following the trigger, but rather uses an element with a specific ID or class (located elsewhere on the page) as the tooltip content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The span tag was the issue; wrapping the Gravity Form in a div tag works perfectly.

This is what happens when you overthink a problem. :-)